# Rust Udp Listener Like Netcat

Tags: rust

I have this code for a reverse shell with tcp in rust

```rs
fn pipe_thread<R, W>(mut r: R, mut w: W) -> std::thread::JoinHandle<()>
where
    R: std::io::Read + Send + 'static,
    W: std::io::Write + Send + 'static,
{
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
        loop {
            let len = r.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
            if len == 0 {
                println!("Connection lost");
                std::process::exit(0x0100);
            }
            w.write(&buffer[..len]).unwrap();
            w.flush().unwrap();
        }
    })
}

fn listen() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let listener = std::net::TcpListener::bind(format!("{}:{}", "0.0.0.0", "55100"))?;
    println!("Started listener");

    let (stream, _) = listener.accept()?;
    let t1 = pipe_thread(std::io::stdin(), stream.try_clone()?);
    println!("Connection recieved");
    let t2 = pipe_thread(stream, std::io::stdout());
    t1.join().unwrap();
    t2.join().unwrap();

    return Ok(());
}
```

How would but would I do the exact same thing but with **udp** instead of tcp?
Netcat example:
netcat -ul 55100

Comment: You cannot do exactly the same thing, because UDP is connectionless protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will listen for udp on port 55100. When it is sent a packet, it will save the address of the sender in the addr variable. Then when the user inputs a command, a udp packet is sent to the addr address.

To test it, first send it a udp packet from port 55101 `nc -u localhost 55100 -p 55101`, this sets addr to localhost:55101. Then listen on port 55101 with `nc -ul localhost 55101` and send a command from the rust program so that the nc listener knows where to send its packets to. Now you should be able to send udp messages back and forth between net cat and the rust program.

```
fn main() {
    let socket = std::net::UdpSocket::bind(format!("{}:{}", "0.0.0.0", "55100"))?;
    println!("Started listener");

    // Addr is the last address that send me a udp packet or None if I have never received a udp packet
    use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
    let addr: Arc<Mutex<Option<std::net::SocketAddr>>> = Arc::from(Mutex::new(None));

    // Clone addr so it can be moved into the closure
    let addr_clone = addr.clone();
    let socket_clone = socket.try_clone().unwrap();
    // Spawn listening loop
    std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
        let (len, src_addr) = socket_clone.recv_from(&mut buffer).unwrap();
        *addr_clone.lock().unwrap() = Some(src_addr);
        print!("{}", std::str::from_utf8(&buffer).unwrap());
    });

    loop {
        // Get user input
        let mut buffer = String::new();
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();

        // Send the command to the last address that send me a udp packet or if I have never received a udp packet, panic
        let addr_option = *addr.lock().unwrap();
        if let Some(addr) = addr_option {
            socket.send_to(buffer.as_bytes(), addr).unwrap();
        } else {
            panic!("Cant send udp because I dont know where to send it.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it kinda works except it prints the lines weird and only sends the first character of the command given

Comment: @Fakebottle I have edited my answer to fix the extra newline printed after receiving UDP messages. However, I cant reproduce it only sending the first character of the command. See this video that shows it working properly https://youtu.be/LW0wz91XotQ

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Tho have you got any idea on how to fix that thing I said in "Rust Command Line History In Reverse Shell" :))